# VHDL: How to rapidly skip over registers that I don't care about?

Tags: vhdl, asic

I have N registers that are M bits wide.  All the registers are filled with values but I only want to sample those registers that fits a certain pattern, such as only look at the registers whose MSB is a 1.  On every rising edge of a clock I want to read one M-bit wide register that meets that pattern.

For example:
There are 256 8-bit registers (reg0 - reg255).  Reg0, Reg3, and Reg255 meets the pattern of the MSB = 1.  On the first rising clock edge, reg0 is sent to the output since it matches the pattern, 2nd rising clock edge Reg3 is sent to the output, and on the 3rd clock edge Reg255 is sent to the output.

I'm very green to HDL so I'd appreciate any assistance.  Is this an application which using a for loop within a clocked process is useful?  Oh, I'm using VHDL to figure this out.

I'm not looking for a complete answer, perhaps just some keywords I should look up.

Thanks,
J

Comment: The best place to start is by drawing a picture of the hardware you intend to create.   Then you will be able to ask some better questions about writing code - but at that point you can probably search on register in VHDL or Multiplexor in VHDL, ....

Comment: As Jim wrote, your first problem is digital hardware design, not HDL coding. It is only once you will have a clear idea of the hardware you want, that the HDL coding will become possible.

Comment: This is not a VHDL question, but a more general design question. I would have put it on the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)
I read two tasks in your description: pattern recognition and multiplexing/bus arbitration. What clock frequency are we talking about? What is the timing requirements? Can this not be achieved using a general purpose processor?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I've taken Jim Lewis' advice and created a drawing of the logic I'm looking for.

For clarification, this is ultimately for an ASIC, not an FPGA.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to do that.

You should use 1 flag (binary register) per register:

This flag that indicate if the pattern is detected in the associated register, it will be use to know which register to send. when the register will be send, this flag will be reset.

At the beginning, you force all register flag to '0' (No pattern detected / No need to send register)

You load data into registers.

A process check if the pattern is detected, in that case set the flag of associated register to '1'

Use amor loop or a BIG if else (not recommended) over flag. If a flag is equal to '1', send the register and reset it. if not, go to the next.
This last step could pass from a register to send to another one in one clock cycle even if they are separate by some other registers (that don't need to be send).

/!\ Be careful, the mechanism is complicate and cause timing constraint, the performance of the clock of your design will be impact and you will use more LUTs.

Best regards, and good luck.